# creating a new table from for loop in java

Tags: java, arrays, spring, spring-boot, for-loop

this is the list of table which is not same data type

```
-DataTableOne 
    int idOne;
    string name;

-DataTableTwo
    int idTwo;
    int id;
```

*getter, setter and service is been implemented for this tow classes*

now i have the list from DataTableOne like 10 records and want to create new DataTableTow in action

```
//i can not create the DataTableTow list by geting the loop from DataTableOne

List<DataTableOne> listOne = service.ListAll(); //will return 10 records
List<DataTableTwo> listTwo = null;

for(DataTableOne row : listOne){
   
   // how to add data of the DataTableOne and add it to the listTwo  

 }
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: i can not create the DataTableTow list by geting the loop from DataTableOne

Comment: update the question check now plz

Comment: this is no relation between two classes,

Comment: well - I doubt it - just use `listTow.add(new DataTableTwo("some id", 42));` or any other values you want  **OR** better explain, in question, what you want to do, maybe including a simple example (1-2 records) - please [edit] the question

Answer (score 1):

//Entity class of the DataTableTwo was not correctly initialized.

```
List<DataTableOne> listOne = service.ListAll(); //will return 10 records
List<DataTableTwo> listTwo = null;

for(DataTableOne row : listOne){
   
   listTwo.add(new DataTableTwo(row.getIdOne(), 1)); //there are two integer and you can form any how you want.

 }
```